# external js from keenthemes metronic theme not working in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, zone, metronic

hey guys so I am using metronic  theme and I made an angular version of demo3 HTML version
and everything looks fine except
if I import external js like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" direction="rtl" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/">

    <script src="assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/pages/widgets.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body  kt-root id="kt_body" class="header-mobile-fixed subheader-enabled aside-enabled aside-fixed aside-secondary-enabled page-loading">

</body>
</html>
```

I don't have any error but toggle buttons not working

and if I added like this to angualr.json file

```
  "scripts": [
          "src/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/js/pages/widgets.js"
        ]
```

when I serve the project I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add

```
import 'core-js';
```

in the polyfills.ts file before the zone

and if you have or imported es6-shim just remove that

and I don't know why your external js not working that's the other problem

Comment: thanks so much the error goes away but js still not working